# How do I change all necessary permissions for virtualenv to run without sudo?

Tags: python, django, permissions, virtualenv

```
$ virtualenv --no-site-packages myenv
The --no-site-packages flag is deprecated; it is now the default behavior.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.7.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.7.1.2-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 928, in main
    never_download=options.never_download)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.7.1.2-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 1029, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.7.1.2-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 1154, in install_python
    mkdir(lib_dir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.7.1.2-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 399, in mkdir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'myenv'
```

I have been struggling to figure out how to be able to get virtualenv to make a new environment without sudo.

Comment: Can you normally create a directory called `myenv` from the directory you are currently in?  Is it possible there is already a file there, or are you running someplace other than your account home directory?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're trying to create your environment in a location that you don't have permission to. Where are you attempting to create the environment? If you're doing this in a shared hosting environment, you want to create your virtualenv in your home directory.

Alternatively, use [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/), and that should take care of most of the decisions you need to make (like where to store your envs).